# Error al subir flexdashboard a shinyapps.io R Rstu

Tags: r, flexdasboard

Tengo una duda del error que obtengo al intentar subir mi flexdashboard a shinyapps.io.
Saben usted a que se debe el error y como se puede solucionar? (adjunto imagen)
Tome como referencia este video de youtube para subir mi flexdashboard a shiyapps.io.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6BFGdLCOXs

[image: Error that I perceive when trying to upload the flexdashboard]

Comment: Si revisas settings --> log, en el cloud de shiny puedes ver que pudo ocasionar el error. De lo contrario, quizás se deba a la estructura de tu código. Por ejemplo, el tamano del archivo, o también puede ser una razón el que hayas modularizado el código de la shiny. En este caso, te recomiendo colocar todo el código en un archivo y ese archivo cargar en shinyapps.io.